# SQL Replace Url Wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to match all records in sql and replace where urls match http://www.test.com/ etc. I need to remove from the beginning of the a tag to the closing tag.

```
For example content may have 
same data here <a href="http://www.test.com/personal/car-leasing/kia/pro ceed/" rel="nofollow" 
target="_blank"><img alt="Contract hire" src="/cms-images/car-hire.jpg" /></a> and here
```

I would need to remove

These links car vary but all start with http://www.test.com/

I tried with the below but am unsure how to escape in a replace statement

```
SELECT content, REPLACE(content, '<a href="http://www.test.com/%','') 
from cms.dbo.tblpost
where id = 47066
```

Comment: `REPLACE` has no wild-cards. Remove the `%` character.

Comment: What's your RDBMS? Depending on the product you use, you might be able to call `REGEX_REPLACE` or something similar.

Comment: i need to match everything  after / until the </a> though thats why i thought i should use a wildcard %

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tblpost TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,content NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @tblpost (content)
VALUES 
    (N'example www.test.com/personal')
    ,(N'example content may have same data here <a href="http://www.test.com/personal/car-leasing/kia/pro ceed/" rel="nofollow" 
target="_blank"><img alt="Contract hire" src="/cms-images/car-hire.jpg" /></a> and here')

DECLARE @Url NVARCHAR(4000) = N'www.test.com'
    ,@OpenTagRev NCHAR(2) = N'a<'       -- Reversed open tag <a href
    ,@CloseTag NCHAR(4) = N'</a>'

;WITH SearchUrl as (
    SELECT ID, content, CHARINDEX ( @Url ,content) UrlPos
    FROM @tblpost
)
, SearchOpenCloseTag as (
    SELECT ID, content, UrlPos, CHARINDEX(@OpenTagRev, REVERSE(LEFT(content, UrlPos))) OpenTagOffset, CHARINDEX ( @CloseTag ,content, UrlPos) CloseTagPos
    FROM SearchUrl
    WHERE UrlPos > 0
)

SELECT ID, content, STUFF(content, UrlPos - OpenTagOffset, CloseTagPos - UrlPos + OpenTagOffset + 4 /* 4 IS LEN(@CloseTag) */, N'') ReplContent
FROM SearchOpenCloseTag
WHERE OpenTagOffset > 0
    AND CloseTagPos > 0
```